tailwindcss installation error with svelte
hello i try to setup a svelte  project with tailwindcss but i encounter this error below when running " npx tailwindcss init -p " i tried to install tailwindcss standalone cli to see if the issue was coming from tailwind but it went good. so i assume it's a issue with svelte
this is the error code :
commande interne
ou externe, un programme exécutable ou un fichier de commandes.       
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1147
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\Green\Desktop\javasctipt projects\svelte\vite\bin\vite.js'
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1144:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:985:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:135:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:28:49 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}

Node.js v20.11.1 ```

